# Assetic not dumping js files using Symfony 2

Tags: assetic

I have the following:

```
//config.yml
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        ['ABundle','BBundle']
    java: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

In some page:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets '@ABundle/Resources/public/css/x.css'
                       '@BBundle/Resources/public/css/y.css' 
                        output='css/general.css' filter='yui_css' %}
            <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

In other page:

```
{% block javascript %}
    {% javascripts 
        '@ABundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
        '@ABundle/Resources/public/js/autoNumeric.js'
        '@ABundle/Resources/public/js/limiter.js.js'
        filter='yui_js' 
     %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
     {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

When from prompt I use:

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console assets:install
```

and finally,

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

I obtain this output:

```
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.

21:39:24 [file+] C:/xampp/htdocs/aplication/app/../web/css/general.css
```

and finish

Why assetic doesn´t dump js files? Css files work fine and are accesible.

Answer (score 3):

I can´t believe it!!!!

After several hours looking for the solution, the problem is a misspelling in this line:

```
'@ABundle/Resources/public/js/limiter.js.js'
```

I change it for:

```
'@ABundle/Resources/public/js/limiter.js'
```

and all work.

Comment: Hi! I had a similar issue with one specific js file. I had a profile.js And I wanted to use @VBundle/Resources/public/js/Profile.js (notice the uppercase file name.) The annoying thing was that it worked at Localhost!! But didn't work on my production server. Fixing the file name fixed the issue but it took me some time to notice... Maybe this will help someone!

Comment: In my case, I had to do `./app/console cache:clear` first. Then `assetic:dump` worked...